# unable to correctly apply XPath from php

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm using xpath to extract data from a web site, but I have a problem with the XPath selector, assuming i have this HTML code:

```
<div id="_parent">
  <div class="my">
      Hi!
      <p>I am a child!</p>
      <span class="someclass">I am a <b>span</b> child!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

what I get:

```
Hi!
I am a child!
I am a span child!
```

what I should get:

```
<div class="my">
    Hi!
    <p>I am a child!</p>
    <span class="someclass">I am a <b>span</b> child!</span>
</div>
```

My current xpath php code

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$entries = $xpath->query("//div[@class='my']");
```

Comment: Share your XPath

Comment: //div[@class='my']

Comment: OK. It should return you `div` instead of just text content. What is the tool you use and how do you use it? Show your code

Comment: i am using domxpath with $node = $xpath->query("//div[@class='my']", $z); in php. Please help me, you are xpath expert, i am searching on web from last 2 hours.

Comment: i added whole code in question.

Answer (score 1):

When in Chrome I open the console and enter this in it:

```
document.evaluate( "//div[@class='my']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;
```

then what I get is:

```
<div class="my">
    Hi!
    <p>I am a child!</p>
    <span class="someclass">I am a <b>span</b> child!</span>
</div>
```

so the XPath expression actually works as intended. So I infer, that the way you apply the XPath expression must be wrong. However you did not show us the code that applies the XPath expression?

Comment: Thanks, but i am using php

Comment: does this work? `$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); $entries = $xpath->query('//div[@class='my']');`